# Is there a site like Bio-Informatics overflow?

Tags: discussion, search, sister-site

I don't know whether this question fits here.

Question - Is there a sister site of stackoverflow in the realm of Bio-Informatics? Some thing like [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) and semanticoverflow which already exist. Is there a site which deals with gene sequencing/gene finding and algorithms involved in Bio-Informatics?

Comment: Note for posterity: There is a [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) site now. It entered public beta in June 2017, and [the beta label was removed from it in December 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/335251).

Answer (score 1):

1 - Take a look at [this list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites)

2 - It doesn't look like there's one

3 - ??

4 - Profit !