# Area 51 reps and badge counts are still being updated for sites that graduated in 2019 or 2021

Tags: support, area-51, statistics, graduating-sites

I have just noticed that the reputation statistics and the badge counts for users of sites that [graduated in 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331708/340816) or [December 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374096/340816) are still being updated, even though the other data are frozen. My understanding was that the Area 51 statistics would be frozen completely, not just the site statistics but also the rankings of top beta users.

Examples for sites that graduated in 2019:

- [French Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language): reps for the top users match reps on the main site, e.g. [jiliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/1109/jlliagre), [None](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/358/none), [Gilles 'SO nous est hostile'](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/5/gilles-so-nous-est-hostile), [LPH](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/17649/lph), etc. Notice that the order given here is based on actual reps, whereas the ranking on Area 51 appears to be based on the reps at the time of graduation.
- [Spanish Language](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language):  reps for the top users match reps on the main site, e.g. [Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie), [Diego](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5481/diego), [pablodf76](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/14627/pablodf76), [fedorqui 'SO stop harming'](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui-so-stop-harming); the ranking on Area 51 does not match the ranking based on current reps.

Examples for sites that graduated in December 2021:

- [Literature](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238): by reps, Spagirl has hopped over Matt Thrower since graduation.
- [Language Learning](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82841/language-learning): no conspicuous differences on the first page, but reps and badge counts represent the current situation.

As a consequence, the rounded orange numbers to the left of the user cards go out of sync with the black numbers for reps inside the user cards.

Is this a bug or is it intentional?

Comment: There are two reputations for each user on that page: One is a larger, usually orange number and the other is in the profile widget. The numbers don't match, so I think the orange number is what it was when beta ended, since the number in the widget is what it is now. (This can even be seen on older graduated proposals.) No comment on anything else — especially the order of users — because everything on Area 51 is just confusing.

Comment: @Laurel You're right, the rounded orange numbers on the left apparently haven't been updated (presumably intended behaviour), just like the numbers of questions and answers. The updates are limited to the user cards.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a new behaviour: it's always been like that. See for example the Area 51 page for [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451/science-fiction-fantasy), which graduated in **2012**. So it's nothing to do with the recent graduations having a different effect on the Area 51 pages.

In every graduated site's Area 51 page, the **orange numbers on the left are fixed** (at the reputation score those users had at the moment of graduation) while the **flair display cards on the right are updated** to the users' current reputation scores. I suppose the visual display is coded by literally just linking to the user's site flair, which is dynamically updated even if it's just displayed as an image in a post. See for example the following image which will update if your rep changes and you hard refresh the page:

[image: Tsundoku flair]

So presumably this isn't a bug and is intended behaviour.