# Are all undesigned graduated sites getting their design?

Tags: support, design, beta-sites, graduating-sites

As of recently SE has hired new developers to make site designs it appears:

- [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1109/custom-bitcoin-design-and-logo-information-gathering?cb=1)
- [Ethereum](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/697/custom-ethereum-design-and-logo-information-gathering?cb=1)
- Others?

There are many more sites that have lost their beta labels, and graduated since SE stopped designing a site as part of them moving out of beta.

For example the list of 29 sites [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta) and the list of 59 sites [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-59-sites-that-just-left-beta?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Is it scheduled that all of these sites will get their own design, and if so are there any criteria that will determine which site gets theirs first?

For the second question it appears that it has to do with the graduation date, as Bitcoin was the first site to have a design independent graduation.